# Generating Java classes using JAXB and xjc maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, xsd

I am new to XJC Maven plugin. I am trying to generate a Java class from XSD. I have placed the XSD file in the location src/main/resources/static/xsd (Say my filename is example.xsd). I have also created a package src/main/java/com/example/message where I expect the sources of my generated Java classes. My pom file looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>demo</name>
  <description>demo</description>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.13.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
    <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
  </properties>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>jboss</id>
      <name>JBoss Repository</name>
      <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>java.net</id>
      <name>Java.net Repository</name>
      <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>codelds</id>
      <url>https://code.lds.org/nexus/content/groups/main-repo</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
      <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
      <version>11.2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>demo</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>xjc</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>xjc</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <packageName>com.example.message</packageName>
          <sources>
            <source>src/main/resources/static/xsd/example.xsd</source>
          </sources>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

But when I build the project, no files are generated in com.example.message. Can anyone please suggest what wrong I am doing?

Comment: Where do you expect genereted classes are placed? You should find then in folder `target\jaxb`

Comment: Can't I et the source code of the generated classes in some folder?

Comment: Also, there is a folder generated named jaxb2 under target, but no classes in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not specify destination folder your generated classes will be placed in `/target/generated-sources/jaxb`. 
I would not place those classes in any folder or package under `src/main/java`: I think that generated files should be dropped and recreated every time you launch the build using Maven. In this way you are sure to have always the correctly generated file.

If you use IntelliJ you should be able to use classes, if you are an Eclipse user then you must add them to source folders (right click on folder -> Build Path -> Use as Source Folder).

You do not need to specify anything to include those classes when producing jar/war files, Maven will automatically include them.

Comment: A general question, if I do not put my generated classes in a source folder, how can I use it in my program? If my code has dependency on those classes, like it will be the input for any REST service where the message will be automatically mapped.

Comment: See my last edit, I should have already answered you while you were writing your comment.

Comment: I think it did not answer my question. Suppose I run maven and my generated classes are generated in the folder specified by packageName. I will never get them at compile time when I am writing a class and want to refer to the generated class.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse? Or IntelliJ?

Comment: I am using Eclipse Luna

Comment: Then locate in Eclipse under your project the folder `target/generated-sources/jaxb`, right click on that folder -> Build Path -> Use as Source Folder. This will allow you to refer that classes.

Comment: I found the answer of my original question, if I want to save the sources, I need to specify <outputDirectory>src/main/java/</outputDirectory> besides <packageName>. But this approach is better!